# UIImagePickerController Delegate is not doing what I need

Tags: objective-c, camera, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I am experiencing difficulty finding a delegate.

You know how we only have 2 delegate method right now in `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
```

The problem is `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:info` would only activated when the capture is trying to save the image.

What I need to do is changing `cameraDevice` when the "capture" button is pressed.

For example, if default `cameraDevice` was Front, when the "capture" button is pressed, it will actually changes its cameraDevice to be Rear and take a picture.

`imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:info` is called after the picture is taken so putting this statement in the delegate method would not work.

```
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
```

I need to find/implement the delegate/method that would actually make this happen.
Anybody can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the default camera interface that Apple provided. You will have to implement your own controls. You can add overlay view on top of the provided camera UI and extend it, but you can't alter the existing controls.

Comment: I guess that means I have to maybe either flip the cameraDevice and take a screen shot of it by custom button IBAction method and crop the image or something.. !! :(

Comment: I guess I would approach with AVCaptureSession API but I don't see if I have control over changing "cameraDevice" to front or rear with this API? Is there any other API that provide changing "cameraDevice"? beside "UIImagePickerController"?